# How to determine where the component is called from? angular

Tags: angular

I have a component that I want to use as a modal

```
     showMyPopup(): void {
    this.matDialog.open(MyComponent, {
      maxWidth: '92vw',
      maxHeight: '90vh',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      position: {
        right: '10px',
        bottom: '6px',
      },
      data: {
        isModalComponent: true,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

and just a page

```
     <app-my-component>

  </app-my-component>
```

how can I determine that this is a modal window? to change its styles inside the component?
i tried like this

```
 constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
console.log(data);
```

}
but this does not work, because an error falls if the window is not modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close - use `@Optional()`

```
 constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data){};

get isModal(){
   return !!this.data;
   
}
```